# Jenkins plain text console output not in real time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

The "html" version console output works fine for me and displays real time from console.

But when I switch to the plain text version (i.e. [image: view as plain text]), it doesn't work.

It only display a small portion of console output until build is complete then it shows full output.

For now the problem only exist on console output that is longer than 5k lines.

Jenkins version: 1.477

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because output is truncated by default around 5k lines, so the full text will always pull the last 5k while the build is in progress, similar to the way the HTML view will only show about 5k lines until you click the "Show Full Output" button.

Once the build completes, the full output gets dumped to plain text, so the entire output is shown.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there a way to change the default value to exceed 5k lines?

Comment: If you want to modify code and build Jenkins from source then this could certainly be done. I don't know of a setting that would allow you to change this.

Comment: @CIGuy, what is the gain from this feature? To me it is all pain. ;)